# is the Emirates website transit lookup web tool the best?

Tags: transit

Through one person's recommendation and one internet search with search terms I do not recall I converged on an Emirates website tool that allows researching transit country restrictions. The relevant inputs are nationality of the traveler and transit country and destination country. This web tool seems to be convenient for finding TWOV (transit without visa) opportunities for people like my travel companion who has a travel-challenged passport.

This is the link...

https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/?NC=IN&AC=&DC=US&TC=&h=999320b24f3fe915d0587d308173a406d5fa3a0

Is this Emirates website tool the best of its kind that you know of in terms of being up-to-date and accurate ?

Comment: The Emirates site is just an interface to Timatic, which is the database used by most people airlines to know what they have to check for each passenger. There are other interfaces to the same data. The data itself is mostly reliable but there have been the occasional error, especially in edge cases.

Comment: @jcaron It would be nice if the Emirates tool were an interface to Timatic but check Philippines to Hong Kong to Canada for a Philippines passport. Emirates says TWOV is possible explicitly within 24 hours whereas Timatic is less explicit and omits mention of 24 hours. This data is as of the time of my invocations today. There is evidence of human intervention.

Comment: For Philippines to Japan to Canada with a Philippines passport, the Emirates web tool has TWOV information where as Timatic is relatively devoid of general TWOV information but it does have "transit health" information. This data is as of the time of my invocations today.